# derivative is absolutely integrable

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that if $f$ is an infinitely differentiable function on the real line that satisfies  $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}f(x)P(x)=0$ for a any polynomial $P(x)$, then it follows that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f'(x)|dx<\infty$$.

I have managed to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx<\infty$ by the following argument:

Since $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}f(x)x^{2}=0$ there exists a sufficiently large $R$ such that if $|x|>R$ then $|f(x)|<\frac{1}{x^{2}}$
and therefore:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx<\int_{-R}^{R}|f(x)|dx+\int_{|x|>R}^{.} \frac{1}{x^2}dx<\infty$$

I'm not sure how my above method can be altered in order to prove the same for the derivative.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Probably you want to consider a function that goes to zero exponentially, but oscillates more and more rapidly.  Here is an example

[image]

$f(x) = e^{-x} \sin(e^x)$

But to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f'(x)|\,dx = +\infty$, you would maybe use a variant that is like this but has an easier antiderivative.  And does the same thing going to $-\infty$.

Comment: e^(-x^2)sin(e^x^2) works :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}f(x)P(x)=0$ for all polynomials $P$, we have $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}(fP)'(x)=0$ (if confused as to why this holds, think about it geometrically) and thus 
$$ \lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}f'(x)P(x)
=\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}\left[(fP)'(x)-f(x)P'(x)\right]
=\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}(fP)'(x)-\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}f(x)P'(x)
=0 $$
for all polynomials $P$.  Now apply your argument.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but please see GEdgar's answer, there a function was given that although tended to zero when x approached infinity, its derivative did not.